# Linear mixed model for monitoring of two groups

Tags: mixed-model, matlab, panel-data, linear

I start straight away by saying that I just started to look into mixed models, so I don't feel very confident of what I understood about them. I have a particular case that I need to analyse, and I'm not sure on how to do it properly.

I have data from 18 subjects, divided in two groups, 12 controls and 6 diseased. The data are repeated measures of the same parameter over time. No specific treatment is performed at any stage, the collection of the data is simply a monitoring procedure. I analysed first one slice of the data acquired at one time point, and the mean of the two groups was significantly different (1-way ANOVA).

Plotting the parameter over time, I can see a lot of variation in the individual subjects (this is why I also want to include random effects), but in general the diseased have still lower values than the controls. I don't expect to find a particular trend in the data over time for the controls and I also expect the diseased data to be stable over time.

My question is: if I don't want to compare a trend over time for the two groups, but only see if the mean of the parameter for the two groups is still significantly different in time, even accounting for the random individual variations, is a linear mixed model still the most appropriate choice?

If so, what could be a good syntax for the model? This is what I got so far, but I'm not sure of anything at the moment (I'm using Matlab statistics toolbox)

$$y \sim 1 + \text{Group} + \text{Time} + (1 + \text{Time}|\text{Subject})$$